# How to use Automapper to map multiple DataTables to an object

Tags: automapper

I've used Automapper before to map DataTable objects to a DTO object like this:

```
AutoMapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyDTO>();
```

Now I've run into a case where I have three DataTable objects that map to one DTO object. I can't use the simple case above because I have three sources with the same type.

Is there a way to specify some additional information, like the table name, to determine the correct mapping?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051852/mapping-from-two-items-with-automapper

Comment: That would work but I would still be limited to one destination type that uses two tables, one that uses three tables, etc. I'm hoping to find a more general solution. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right sorry, you can make a class using the same funcionality that automapper provides for mapping as shown in this link http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/22/automapper-mapping-from-multiple-objects.aspx